# My Mocked DbContext writes to db in Unit Test using Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am new to mocking and using Moq. This is my first time trying to Mock the add functionality. I have the mocks setup and it works for read functions, but when I try to unit test an add method, it saves the changes to the db.

How do I mock the add method?

I think I have to Mock my `UnitOfWork` class which has the `SaveChanges()` method. I want to know how I have to setup the mock to intercept the call to `SaveChanges()` and not save to db.

Here are the Mocks I have so far

```
[SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        addCount = 0;

        IEnumerable<Platform> platformList = new List<Platform>(){
            new Platform() { Id = 1, Name = "Unknown"},
            new Platform() { Id =2, Name = "Amazon"},
            new Platform() { Id = 3, Name = "Prime Pantry"}
        };
        var platformData = platformList.AsQueryable();

        var mockPlatformSet = new Mock<DbSet<Platform>>();
        mockPlatformSet.As<IQueryable<Platform>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(platformData.Provider);
        mockPlatformSet.As<IQueryable<Platform>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(platformData.Expression);
        mockPlatformSet.As<IQueryable<Platform>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(platformData.ElementType);
        mockPlatformSet.As<IQueryable<Platform>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(platformData.GetEnumerator());
        mockPlatformSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Platform>())).Callback(() => addCount++);

        var mockContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>(){ CallBase = true };
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Platforms).Returns(mockPlatformSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Platforms.Add(It.IsAny<Platform>()));
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Platforms.Add(It.IsAny<Platform>())).Callback(() => addCount++);


        unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(mockContext.Object);
        platformRepo = new PlatformRepository(mockContext.Object);

        controller = new PlatformController(platformRepo, unitOfWork);
    }
```

Adding UnitOfWork code

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork 
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private bool _isDisposed = false;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

}
```

***Updated question***

I am trying to Unit Test my `Create` method of my `PlatformController`. In this method, I call the `Add` function on the repostiory then the `SaveChanges` function of `UnitOfWork`. I want to verify that my `Platform` object gets added to the DbSet, but 'intercept' the call to `SaveChanges()` to that it does not write to db.

How can I do this?

Comment: When I tried to do mocking, I Mocked the collections on the context instead.

Comment: Can you please add the code for the `UnitOfWork` constructor where the context gets injected?

Comment: @elolos I added the UnitOfWork code

Comment: It seems that the `SaveChanges` method is not being setup for `mockContext`. Still, I don't understand why would anything get saved in the database, given that you inject a mock context. The code in `UnitOfWork` looks fine too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I set the `CallBase` value of my `mockContext` as `IUnitOfWork` to `false`, that seems to have solved the problem of my unit test writing to the database.

This line of code:
`mockContext.As<IUnitOfWork>().CallBase = false;`

Here is the code of my `Setup` function

```
[SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        addCount = 0;

        IEnumerable<Platform> platformList = new List<Platform>(){
            new Platform() { Id = 1, Name = "Unknown"},
            new Platform() { Id =2, Name = "Amazon"},
            new Platform() { Id = 3, Name = "Prime Pantry"}
        };
        var platformData = platformList.AsQueryable();

        var mockPlatformSet = new Mock<DbSet<Platform>>();
        mockPlatformSet.As<IQueryable<Platform>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(platformData.Provider);
        mockPlatformSet.As<IQueryable<Platform>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(platformData.Expression);
        mockPlatformSet.As<IQueryable<Platform>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(platformData.ElementType);
        mockPlatformSet.As<IQueryable<Platform>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(platformData.GetEnumerator());
        mockPlatformSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Platform>())).Callback(() => addCount++);

        var mockContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>(){ CallBase = true };
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Platforms).Returns(mockPlatformSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Platforms.Add(It.IsAny<Platform>()));
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Platforms.Add(It.IsAny<Platform>())).Callback(() => addCount++);
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<Platform>()).Returns(mockPlatformSet.Object);
        mockContext.As<IUnitOfWork>().CallBase = false;

        unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(mockContext.Object);
        platformRepo = new PlatformRepository(mockContext.Object);

        controller = new PlatformController(platformRepo, unitOfWork);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the answer you were looking for, but abstracting the EF `DbContext` with a Unit of Work is a terrible idea. The reason is that the context already **is** a Unit of Work implementation. According to the description of the class in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.103).aspx):

> Represents a combination of the Unit-Of-Work and Repository patterns
>   and enables you to query a database and group together changes that
>   will then be written back to the store as a unit.

Once you remove the unnecessary abstraction, mocking the context should be fairly easy, especially if you use the newest version of Entity Framework.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but for this project that is not going to happen. The abstraction is too integrated for it to be removed now, with the timeline.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to do functional testing here, so it would be wise to have a functional database.

EF can recreate and destroy your database in your setup and teardown methods with a test connection string. This would provide a real functional testing environment for your tests to operate against mimicking the real environment.

Ex:

```
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public static void SetupFixture() //create database
    {
        using (var context = new XEntities())
        {
            context.Setup();
        }
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TearDown() //drop database
    {
        using (var context = new XEntities())
        {
            context.Database.Delete();
        }
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup() //Clear entities before each test so they are independent
    {
        using (var context = new XEntities())
        {
            foreach (var tableRow in context.Table)
            {
                context.Table.Remove(tableRow);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Change your connection string in your test project to point to "DbNameTest" and you're gold to use your XEntities class in your tests and it will be clear for setting up and adding test data to interact with.

Comment: I think he wants to write unit tests, not integration/functional tests.

Comment: Yeah but when you're testing the functionality of a database interaction, you're doing a functional test. He might think he wants unit tests, but he's actually testing the functionality when calling add(). This way he can, instead of hitting his prod DB, hit a test db created by EF for this functional testing.

Comment: I think most projects need both. There is no `Assert` statement, but if he wants to test just the controller logic in isolation, then it's a unit test.

Comment: I did not include my Unit Tests, but I do have them. My goal is to test the functions in the Controller(MVC)

Comment: @DFord are you testing that you CALL add() function, or are you testing that an entity was ADDED to the context?

Comment: @CBauer that the entity was added. I test that its added to the DbSet.

Comment: Then you are performing a functional test, and should use my example. Just change the connection string in your app.config in your test project to change it to `DatabaseNameTests`